# jQuery events not working together with ASP.NET MVC partial view

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have read a lot about this problem here on Stackoverflow and on other sources and realize that this is a big problem. I have tested several solutions, but it still doesn't work!

Is it really possible to combine jQuery and partial views!? If I understand it correct, the classes inside of the partial view losing there bindings and and never triggers when a click is done and that the content of the partial view isn't loaded into the DOM!? Is this the reason why it's not working?

Any ideas how I can fix this problem and make my application running? Any special guidelines when using jQuery with partial views?

Instead of common click events like this:

```
$(".modalOpen").click(function (e) {....
```

I have tested this instead

```
$( ".modalOpen" ).on( "click", function() {...
```

But nothing triggers! And I know that all jQuery script works, because it was after I changed some code and used AJAX to load from Controller to View and insert it into a div tag, that I discovered that it stopped working.

I have also tested to change the order to have the external .js file in the top or the bottom of the page and the same with the jQuery file. And I have tested to have the script inside of the View file (Index.cshtml) and external. But still no success.

In the `_Layout.cshtml` I have this in the head:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/project.css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/myScript.js")
</head>
```

This is a little part of the `Index.cshtml` Main View:

```
<div class="modal">

<div class="modalBox">

    <div class="modalClose">X</div>
    <h4>Headline</h4>

    Content here....

</div>
```

I have all the events and other javascript code in `myScript.js`

I can load the content via AJAX after I click on a button into the partial view, but when I try to click on a buttons to open an modal window, nothing happens inside of the partial view!

Inside of the `Index.cshtml` file:

```
<div class="testAjax">Test</div>
<div id="ListOfProducts"></div>
```

And this is the AJAX script that loads the content from the Controller and it's inside of the `myScript.js`:

```
function LoadProducts(){
$.ajax({
        url: "/Products/TestPartialView2",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "HTML",
        cache: false,
        data: { }
    })

    .done(function (updateView) {
    $("#ListOfProducts").html(updateView);
    });
    }
```

Comment: It needs to be `$( document ).on( "click", ".modalOpen" , function() {...` if the element with `class="modalOpen"` is loaded dynamically (but replace `document` with the closest ancestor which exists when the view is first rendered.

Comment: @StephenMuecke OK, a console.log message shows when I click now. Nice! But the content inside of the function like ´$(".modalBox").fadeIn();´ not working and the HTML code for this is in the Index.cshtml file from the beginning. Do I also have to change something else?

Comment: You have not shown enough code to understand what your doing :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Not easy to decide how much and what to add in a question. To beginn with I just want to find a reason why my modal window and other element are still hidden despite that I use .show() and .fadeIn() after I click and call a function!?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Any particular code that I can add?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I'm not a specialist in how jQuery really works, but what if the problem is like this: I have an element with the class modalBox int the HTML code from the beginning and when the document loads for the first time into the DOM and then I add the partial view later with the element with the button that triggers the element with class modalBox to show up. Does the DOM/code knows each other!?

Comment: You have mentioned `´$(".modalBox").fadeIn();` but you have not shown anything related to an element with that class name. Does it exist? Is it in the partial or the main view? Where are you calling that line of code? You have to give me something to understand what your wanting to do :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I added some of the code in the Main View (Index.cshtml), yes the code excist! I have checked. I'm calling this with a button inside of the Partial View and the jQuery/javascript for this event is in an external .js file. When I click in this button I want other things to happen like the modal window to open and the modal class to darken the background. All this worked fine before I start using partial view. I had a lot of events and none of them works after I started to use partial view. Was this any help?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110363/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-3d-kreativ).